# $! returns "not found" when executed in a shell function

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pid

I'm trying to monitor the duration and cpu/mem usage of a compile command, to do this i want to use the pid of the compile command which is want to get using $!.

This is my script, i'm testing it on the sleep command for now

```
#!/bin/sh
FILE_EXTENSION="$(date +"%d-%m-%Y-%T")"
TIME_FILE_NAME=outout/test_duration_$FILE_EXTENSION.txt
RESOURCES_FILE_NAME=output/test_internal_resources$FILE_EXTENSION.csv

monitorResources(){
    PID=$1
    echo "the pid i found is $($PID)"
    mkdir -p output
    echo "TIME_STAMP, Usage%, Memory Usage (MB)" > "$RESOURCES_FILE_NAME"
    TOTAL="$(free -m | grep Mem | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2)"
    while ps -p "$PID" > /dev/null
    do 
        logResources "$PID" "$TOTAL"
    done
}

logResources(){
    PID=$1
    TOTAL=$2

    echo "logging procces $(PID)"
    DATE=$(date +"%H:%M:%S:%s%:z")
    echo "$DATE, " >> "$RESOURCES_FILE_NAME"
    top -b -n 1 -p "$PID" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 10 >> "$RESOURCES_FILE_NAME"
    ##VAR="$(top -b -n 1 -p $PID | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 11)"
    ##echo "scale=3; ($VAR*$TOTAL/100)" | bc >> $RESOURCES_FILE_NAME

    sleep 1
}

##cd /php-src
##{ time make -j $(nproc) ; } > $TIME_FILE_NAME 2>&1 &
sleep 5 &
monitorResources $!

wait
cat "$TIME_FILE_NAME"
cat "$RESOURCES_FILE_NAME"
```

currently this returns:

```
./run_test.sh: 1: 1209: not found
./run_test.sh: 1: the: not found

./run_test.sh: 22: PID: not found
logging procces
./run_test.sh: 22: PID: not found
logging procces
```

Should i pass the variable differently? I've tried using pgrep aswell but that gave similar results. I'm pretty new to shell scripting.

Comment: `$($PID)"` you are executing pid ? `$(PID)"` executing PID? To access a variable use `$PID`. To _run a command_ use `$( the command to run )`.

Comment: ahh, that makes me feel stupid. I was thinking it was similar to string literals in other programming languages and i needed the $() to use a variable. As I said, new to shell scripting

Thank you!

Comment: you can put your code in https://www.shellcheck.net/ to get some syntax hints and solutions

Comment: if you’re trying to separate variables use curly braces instead : ${PID}